# Front wheel is not aligned and touching the brake line

Tags: repair, disc-brake

On my bike the front wheel is not centered below the handlebars, instead it seems to be more on the left side. Weirdly that's also the side where the disk brake is located and the wheel is touching the brake line.

How can this be fixed?

It's a Cube Travel Pro, recently bought from a private seller, so no guarantee.

[image: Top View]

[[image: side view brakes2]

[image: side view]

[image]

Comment: I would definitely not ride that bike until the wheel is sorted out. You risk rubbing all the way through the brake line, resulting in a likely brake failure.

Comment: @MaplePanda I'd also look very closely at that brake line with a view to replacing it.  Even a thinning of the line could promote a weak spot - it looks to be a hydraulic line so pressurised.

Comment: The brake line is fine, that gunk seems to be only from the tire. I fixed the line to the front of the fork, away from the tire for now

Comment: Was the bike like this when you got it, or has the problem developed or appeared?

Comment: It was like this when I got it. But I didn't notice right away

Comment: Probably incorrectly built, you need to heave the lacing re-built.

Comment: I will try to get in contact with the seller and manufacturer to see, if they are willing to do anything about it

Comment: Insert the wheel the other way around to confirm that it’s built asymmetrical. (of course the disc will be on the wrong side, only do it temporarily)

Comment: @Michael No the spokes collide with the brake calliper, but the spacing between the fork seems ok. Not sure if that says anything.

Answer (score 5):

First thing to do is loosen the quick release and make sure the wheel axles are seated all the way in the dropouts. If the left axle was not all the way in it would pull the top of the wheel to the left.

If the wheel is in the dropouts properly I have to conclude the wheel is built incorrectly, with the rim offset to the left. The hub does not seem shifted left and the disc rotor is aligned with the caliper. If the hub were shifted left as far as the rim you would not be able to adjust the caliper properly.

Comment: thanks for input, I tried resetting the tire several times with no luck. everthings sits flush in the fork

Comment: @Christian see edits

Comment: There's also a possibility that the fork is bent.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I guess that is true but enough force to bend the fork would surely leave obvious marks

Comment: No visible marks on the fork, It's aluminium which afaik doesn't bent but break

Comment: I've heard disc wheels are dished a bit to the left, but can't support this with a good reference. Based on what I'm seeing and reading here, the problem lies with the wheel build.  That makes even more sense if in fact it's necessary to put aittle left dish on a disc wheel...in this case too much

Comment: I’d hazard a guess and suggests the forks have been taken off at some point, maybe twisted / bent. If you look at the cube website you can see the original cable routing for your front light would have gone between the fork and guard. I checked both 2019 and 2020 variants of your bike the only differences I found were the front light cable routing and the QR is on disc side so the opposite way to how you have it

Comment: @DanK It's the 2018 version, I will see if I can find the picutres you mention

Comment: I found what you're talking about, there is also a cable tie on the front light which might point to a later fix